# RabbitMQ connection with AIO_PIKA

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq

Is it possible to make a global connection (not in function) with aio pika somehow? I need to connect it to my rabbitmq queue

Comment: aio pika is an asynchronous framework, so a connection outside a coroutine does not make much sense. You can of course instanciate a Connection object globally, but still you can only connect within a coroutine. It is not clear what you really want to achieve.

Comment: Okay that’s all i wanted to know, also, is it possible to make a connection using PIKA and then use some Aio_pika funcfions?

Comment: You should better not mix up the concepts. Generally, if your application is async use the async version if not use the "sync/blocking" version. It would be helpful if you could share a minimal example of what you are trying to do. Maybe the global connection is not really needed in your application.